# Global variables in imported class functions in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, global-variables

I'm trying to spread my code across separate files to improve readability, and I'm running in to trouble with undefined global names being referenced inside imported files.  Is there a better solution than deliberately passing all necessary values to the functions when called?

My code currently is like this:

```
#foo.py

import bar

def main():
    a = 1
    b = bar.Bar()
    while True:
        a += 1
        b.incr()
        print a
        print b.c

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

#END foo.py
```

-

```
#bar.py

class Bar:
    def __init__(self):
        self.c = 0
    def incr(self):
        self.c += a

#END bar.py
```

It gives me NameError: global name 'a' is not defined.  Do I need to rewrite main() like this:

```
def main():
        b = new bar.Bar()
        while True:
            a += 1
            b.incr(a)
            print a
            print b.c
```

And rewrite incr() like this:

```
def incr(self,a):
            c += a
```

Or is there a better way?

For the record, the above code is heavily abstracted.  The actual code involves a great many classes and functions passing many variables of several types, including some large dictionaries.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since global variables are usually not a good idea, passing in variables from function to function is the better option.

Comment: passing a to `incr()` is a better idea

Comment: Thanks @PurityLake and MartijnPieters - with regards to performance, is that not a problem?  Is there a good solution for passing large amounts of variables from function to function?  Stick them all in to a dictionary, or a dictionary of dictionaries, maybe?

Comment: Passing variables can be easier as if you are expanding the dictionary alot, it can grow to exponential sizes and can sometimes become quite unmanageable and cause breaks in the code if you are not careful

Comment: @PurityLake I guess what I'm stuck on is that it seems like a fairly clunky and unwieldy and inelegant way to go about things in a language known for being the antithesis of all those things.  If that's how it is, that's how it is - all languages have their quirks - but maybe I'm just not grokking how doing it this way is Pythonic.

Comment: Accessing locals is faster than accessing globals, and the globals dictionary is generally a lot bigger, making things even worse. So it's probably not a problem; it's probably an improvement. And performance is incredibly unlikely to be relevant here anyway. But if it is a problem, make it an object attribute on the `Bar` instance. And use `__slots__` instead of an instance dictionary. Or move `Bar` into Cython. Or…

Comment: The textbook use of objects is to associate data with functions.  If you have long-lived data that is consumed/modified by some set of functions regularly, that's what an object is for.  If you are finding you need some data from one object often in another, then you probably need inheritance, composition, or to redesign your code.

Comment: Or, if you really need this to be fast, pass `a` into `Bar.__init__` and use it to generate an instance-specific `incr` function with the value of `a` bound into its closure. (And then try running it on PyPy instead of CPython, where the second time you call `bar.incr()` it'll probably end up compiling the whole thing to a single add-immediate opcode.)

Comment: @sr2222 what I'm trying to do is have some global properties that affect several classes' internal functions.  More practically, let's say a `gravity` variable that affects the `ypos` of `Rock`, `Paper`, and `Parrot`, all according to those classes' own `resistance`s.  If `gravity` never changed, great, I could pass it in with each object's `__init__`, but maybe something will alter `gravity` - then what?

Comment: @yoel: What about passing a `config` dictionary to each object's `__init__`, so main can change `config['gravity'] = 2`, and `Rock` can check `self.config['gravity']` and find the new value? Or you can make the config a class instance instead of a dict, so it's `self.config.gravity`. Is there a problem with one of those?

Comment: @abarnert that sounds pretty great - but if main changes `config['gravity']`, does that change a prexisting `Rock`'s `self.config['gravity']` too?

Comment: @yoel: Yes, if… let me explain in my answer instead of trying to get too deep in a comment.

Comment: @abarnert good plan :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to know why it's not working:

First, `main` isn't setting a global `a`, but a local one. If you want to make it global, you have to be explicit:

```
def main():
    global a
    a = 1
    # ...
```

But this won't fix the problem, because "global" in Python is per-module. In other words, that just creates a `foo.a`, but your code in `bar.Bar` will be looking for `bar.a`, which will not exist.

You could `import foo` and then access `foo.a` if you wanted. (In this case, the circular dependency shouldn't be a problem, and the `if __name__ == '__main__'` won't get executed twice.) Or you could assume that `foo` has been imported, and use `sys.modules['foo'].a`. Or you could inject `a` into `bar`'s dictionary from `foo`. Or lots of other tricks. But these are all horrible things to do.

If you can't make a global work, the right answer is almost always to not use a global. (In fact, even when you *can* make a global work, that's usually the right answer.)

So, how do you do that? Without knowing more about the details, it's hard to guess whether `a` belongs as an explicit module global, a class attribute, an instance attribute, a parameter to `incr`, etc. But figure out which one makes the most sense given what `a` represents, and do that.

---

In the comments, you suggested that you have a bunch of these configuration variables. If you wrap them all up in a `dict` and pass that `dict` to each object's constructor, that will make things simpler.

More importantly, a `dict` is a reference to a mutable object. Copying it just makes another reference to that same object.

main.py:

```
def main():
    configs = {}
    configs['gravity'] = 1.0
    rock = rps.Rock(configs)
    rock.do_stuff()
    configs['gravity'] = 2.1
    rock.do_stuff()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

rps.py:

```
class Rock(object):
    def __init__(self, configs):
        self.configs = configs
    def do_stuff(self):
        print('Falling with gravity {}.'.format(self.configs['gravity']))
```

When you run this, it'll print something like:

```
Falling with gravity 1.0.
Falling with gravity 2.1.
```

You haven't modified the value `configs['gravity']` (that's an immutable float; you can't modify it), but you *have* replaced it with a different value (because `configs` is a mutable `dict`; you can modify it just fine). You can try printing out things like `id(self.configs)`, `id(self.configs['gravity'])`, etc. in various places if the identity isn't clear.

Comment: Thanks - just to make sure I understand: if `configs['gravity']` is equal to 1 and I say `configs['gravity'] = 2`, it removes the old `'gravity'` and makes a new one?  So when a previously created object goes to look it up, it only finds the new value?

Comment: @yoel: Yes, you've got it. When you do `configs['gravity'] = 2`, anyone who does `configs['gravity']` after that—or `foo['gravity']` if `foo` is a reference to the same dictionary as `configs`—will see `2`.

Answer (score 2):

If `a` is a characteristic or configuration of `Bar`, it should be an instance or class attribute thereof.

```
class Bar(object):
    class_step = 1
    def __init__(self, inst_step):
        self.inst_step = inst_step
        self.c = 0
        self.step_mode = 'class'
    def inc(self):
        self.c += Bar.class_step if self.step_mode == 'class' else self.inst_step
```

Comment: Thanks - it's not.  Let's say that `a` is used not just by `Bar`, but also by `Spam`, `Eggs`, and `Toast`.

Comment: Then share a configuration object between all the classes that need to use the data...